# How to obtain individual IDs in the matrix, instead of row names in R (sf package)?

Tags: r, r-sf

I obtained a matrix of distances between each species ID. How do I get the matrix to show the actual ID of individuals instead of row numbers?

```
library(sf)

species <- data.frame(longitude = c(-106.425668, -96.111617, -96.5,-96.5, -96.5, -96.5), 
                      latitude = c(23.18127, 15.779873, 19.68, 19.68, 19.68, 19.68), 
                      id = c("0-1","0-2","0-3","0-4","0-5","0-6"))

species_sf <- st_as_sf(species, coords = c("longitude", "latitude"), crs = 4326)

st_distance(species_sf)
```

My output is below:

```
Units: [m]
        [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,]       0 1357855.2 1098291.3 1098291.3 1098291.3 1098291.3
[2,] 1357855       0.0  435620.5  435620.5  435620.5  435620.5
[3,] 1098291  435620.5       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
[4,] 1098291  435620.5       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
[5,] 1098291  435620.5       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
[6,] 1098291  435620.5       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
```

I want the square brackets to show actual species IDs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set names with `rownames()` & `colnames()` :

```r
species_sf |>
  st_distance() |>
  `rownames<-`(species_sf$id) |>
  `colnames<-`(species_sf$id)
#> Units: [m]
#>         0-1       0-2       0-3       0-4       0-5       0-6
#> 0-1       0 1357855.2 1098291.3 1098291.3 1098291.3 1098291.3
#> 0-2 1357855       0.0  435620.5  435620.5  435620.5  435620.5
#> 0-3 1098291  435620.5       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
#> 0-4 1098291  435620.5       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
#> 0-5 1098291  435620.5       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
#> 0-6 1098291  435620.5       0.0       0.0       0.0       0.0
```